# HTML Bootstrap PHP connection error

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to write log in code for my index.html ' s form and i wrote a giris-yap.php file which is at below. i cant access my php file browser get alert only like localhost is waiting .
 i tried to put action method in my form's submit button but it was not usefull.

giris-yap.php

```
    <?php
require "connect.inc.php";
require "core.inc.php";

if(isset($_POST['exampleInputEmail1']) && isset($_POST['exampleInputPassword1']) ){
    $mail=$_POST['exampleInputEmail1'];
    $pass=$_POST['exampleInputPassword1'];
    $password=md5($pass);
    if($query_run=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `e-mail`= '".mysql_real_escape_string($mail)."' AND `sifre`='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)." ' ")){
        $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if($query_num_rows==0){
            echo 'Invalid';
        }
        else if($query_num_rows!=0){
            $ad=mysql_result($query_run,0,'Ad');
            $_SESSION['ad']=$ad;
            $usersurname=mysql_result($query_run,0,'SoyAd');
            $_SESSION['usersurname']=$usersurname;
            $username=mysql_result($query_run,0,'e-mail');
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            header('Location: index.html');
        }
    }
    else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
else{echo 'error';}
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: bilsay
 * Date: 21.05.2015
 * Time: 10:35
 */

?>
```

index.html :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal-box" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <form action="#giris-kontrol" method="POST">


            <div class="modal-dialog user-login-box-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Kullanıcı Giriş Paneli</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Eposta Adresiniz</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Şifre</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                          </div>

                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox"> Beni hatırla
                            </label>
                          </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Giriş">Giriş</button>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

            </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: FYI - mysql_* is deprecated. Please stop using it.  Use PDO or mysqli.  Also, please don't hash passwords with MD5. If your DB is ever compromised, an MD5 hash can be compromised with brute force on GPU systems in seconds or minutes. Most people use the same passwords everywhere, so you may be compromising your user's banking passwords, etc.  You need to use a "slow hashing" algorithm like BCrypt.  the `password_hash` method in PHP will do this for you in PHP >= 5.5, or `crypt` in older versions with a `2y` salt (see docs), and use a `slow_equals` method to verify password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cant access my php file

You need to update your `action` as described in the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30377560/482256.

Then, note that this code here:

```
require connect.inc.php;
require core.inc.php;
```

Is the equivalent of doing this:

```
require 'connectincphp';
require 'coreincphp';
```

When you don't use quotes, PHP looks for `constants`, and when it doesn't find those it will assume the string, so `connect` becomes `"connect"`.  The period concatenates, so it combines "connect" with "inc" and you get "connectinc", etc.

The require should be causing a 500 error...and possibly an empty page depending on what your error output settings are.

Your code translated to PDO and BCrypt, because I just can't "fix" code and leave it insecure:

```
if(isset($_POST['exampleInputEmail1']) && isset($_POST['exampleInputPassword1']) ){
    $pdo        = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=dbName;host=localhost','username','password');
    $mail       = $_POST['exampleInputEmail1'];
    $pass       = $_POST['exampleInputPassword1'];

    $userSql    = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `e-mail`=:email");
    $userSql->execute(array('email'=>$mail));
    $userData   = $userSql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if( $userData !== false && BCrypt::isValidPassword($pass, $userData['sifre']) ) {
        $_SESSION['ad']             = $userData;
        $_SESSION['usersurname']    = $userData['SoyAd'];
        $_SESSION['username']       = $userData['username'];
        header('Location: index.html');
    }
    else {
        die("You have entered an invalid username or password");
    }
}
else{
    die("Username and Password must be submitted");
}
```

And your modified HTML.  I fixed the action, turned your button into a real submit button, and added the `name=` attributes to your inputs:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal-box" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form action="giris-yap.php" method="POST">

        <div class="modal-dialog user-login-box-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Kullanıcı Giriş Paneli</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Eposta Adresiniz</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Şifre</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox"> Beni hatırla
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" value="1" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit"> Giriş Yap</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

    </form>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And the BCrypt class you will need.  However, use `password_hash` and `password_verify` if you have PHP >= 5.5.

```
class BCrypt {
    public static function hash( $password, $cost=12 ) {
        $base64 = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(17));
        $salt   = str_replace('+','.',substr($base64,0,22));
        $cost   = str_pad($cost,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $algo   = version_compare(phpversion(),'5.3.7') >= 0 ? '2y' : '2a';
        $prefix = "\${$algo}\${$cost}\${$salt}";

        return crypt($password, $prefix);

    }
    public static function isValidPassword( $password, $storedHash ) {
        $newHash    = crypt( $password, $storedHash );
        return self::areHashesEqual($newHash,$storedHash);
    }
    private static function areHashesEqual( $hash1, $hash2 ) {
        $length1    = strlen($hash1);
        $length2    = strlen($hash2);
        $diff       = $length1 ^ $length2;
        for($i = 0; $i < $length1 && $i < $length2; $i++) {
            $diff |= ord($hash1[$i]) ^ ord($hash2[$i]);
        }
        return $diff === 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: you are right;  how have not catched it but i still get error.

Comment: @el_Pueblo_13, please update your question with the modified source code and what error you are getting from it.

Comment: @el_Pueblo_13, if you want to venture into the world of PDO and secure password hashing, I've updated your code (I must have been bored :) )

Comment: @el_Pueblo_13, and note that your on-going issue is probably that you have an `id=` and not `name=` for your username and password.  When a form submits, it submits the names, not the Ids.

Answer (score 1):

change action..

```
<form action="giris-yap.php" method="POST">
```

then change a link in your modal-footer

```
<button type="submit" value="Giriş Yap" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" />
```

Comment: <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Giriş">Giriş</button>
                </div> i write this but i can not still connect php file .